# springs Inversion of control

Tags: spring

In case of normal javacode without spring, We are creating objects whenever there is a new operator, but still the object gets garbage collected and frees the memory whenever it goes out of scope, Will spring helps in any way to do memory management or just reduces coding effort?

Comment: It depends upon the scope setup by the container. Usually, scopes can be *lengthened* via an IoC container (e.g. singletons or per-connection/request), but not shortened. That is, strong references/reachability will *always* keep an object alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring, Object created by container is by default singleton and survives till application is live. This object never goes out of scope. This is helping in memory management for the cases where we have stateless beans thus reusing the same bean for every thread. This reduces the coding effort as compared to java where we explicitly need to create singleton.
Here few annotations help us achieve the same.